# Пользовательская сортировка в фронтэнде

Tags: drupal, сортировка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в `views drupal7` разрешить пользователю сортировать(по убыванию или возрастанию) список  нод?

Сейчас я вывел список нод типа `product`. Каждая нода принадлежит определенному термину таксономии и имеет поле "цена". Я реализовал возможность сортировки пользователем по термину таксономии. Теперь вместо этого хотелось бы просто дать возможность пользователю вывести ноды в порядке возрастания или убывания значения поля "цена"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во views при изменении параметра сортировки есть флаг "Раскройте эту сортировку для посетителей, чтобы позволить им изменять ее"